# Chrome bookmarks are duplicating over and over after each sync ... How to avoid?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, bookmarks, google-sync

facts:

- I use several pcs of Win7 and Ubuntu which Chrome-synced with my Google account.
- I am using Chrome since it's v.1. at that time it had not "sync"option. I used xbookmark or something like that at that time. Now, i use nothing for that except Chrome's sync.
- while sync, i keep all the "sync" options enabled.

Can I undo that and avoid that for future syncs?

snapshot:

[image]

Comment: you should file this a bug with Chrome. https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list

Answer (score 2):

As Sathya said, file a bug report, to clean up the duplicates use the chrome extension [Bookmark Sentry](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bookmark-sentry/bdglbbcbmgnimogcmcdenggkpdmihlga?hl=en).